# VS2010 linking of static library behave differently in separate solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, linker

Lets say I have a solution `S1` with two projects `pdep` and `pmaster`, respectively creating a static and dynamic library. I have the configurations:

- release win32 : produces `pdep.lib`
- debug win32   : produces `pdepd.lib`
- release x64   : produces `pdepx64.lib`
- debug x64     : produces `pdepx64d.lib`

`pmaster` link configuration is done by `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`
**No #pragma comment(lib ) in the code. No common properties references.**

What I observe :

- In s1 with both pdep and pmaster the command line for the linker is fine. ie `/LIBPATH:"c:\pdep\lib\x64\Release" "pdepx64.lib"`
- In a solution S2 freshly created by clicking on the project pmaster, **I always have an additional line with an absolute path to a specific version of pdep, regardless of the configuration.** ie `/LIBPATH:"c:\pdep\lib\x64\Release" "pdepx64.lib" "c:\pdep\lib\pdepd.lib"`

How does the linker in S2 derives the additional option `"c:\pdep\lib\pdepd.lib"`?
 How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @leppie dont remove the vs2010 tag

Comment: You are not developing something for VS2010. It like tagging every Ruby question with Vim...

Comment: @leppie It may be related to the specific IDE, why remove the tag?

Comment: IMO, tag is valid. Please don't remove it.

Comment: @leppie, Does it mean that all `C++` guys here are working on `C++` compiler?

Comment: @leppie I would have love too if visual studio didnt radically change behavior between versions. But it does.

Comment: So S1 contains pdep.vcxproj but S2 doesn't?  If so - that is a known (and reasonable) source for a change in behaviour.

Comment: Setting that LIBPATH argument requires changing a setting.  You never mentioned it in your question.  So high odds that you just got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possibilities:

- Common Properties -> References
- Link Library Dependencies in Linker or Librarian section. This assumes that Project Dependencies have been setup.
- `#pragma comment(lib...)` is playing some role

Comment: Okay. Why don't you open the .SLN or .VCXProj file in text editor and do a find? May be something buried down there, which VS isn't showing you. One such example is `/prefast` option.

Comment: Ajay it is indeed `Link Library Dependencies`. I attached debugview and in the later case and MSBuild is trying to resolve things by himself like a big boy. And fail. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the project file using msbuild with a preprocess flag.  Then load that into a plain text or xml editor. Look at the linker command and see what $(properties) hold the options, and then look at where that is being set.

With msbuild you can also use more verbose logging and it will report which conditions are evaluated and such.